# Java создание музыки как в Keygen

Tags: java, аудио

**Задача:** требуется синтезировать музыку в стиле chiptune/как в Keygen.

В конечном счете должен получиться простенький трекер. Задача усложняется тем, что нужно это реализовать на Java, т.е. код должен в реальном времени **генерировать звуки**. Пробовал работать с `javax.sound.midi` используя `Sequencer`, `MidiEvent` и тд - там все ясно, но это имитация реальных инструментов, т.е. совсем не то, что нужно.

Нужна возможность генерировать звук с нуля, используя формулы для расчета. Я так понимаю мне нужно использовать `javax.sound.sampled`, этот пакет проигрывает все что угодно, включая генерированный кодом звук. Но как именно генерировать звук? где взять формулы? где искать примеры на Java? как создавать эффект chiptune в программе?

В сети есть тысячи keygen'ов с музыкой, но мне не удалось найти исходника ни к одному из них. В основном много инфы как проиграть v2m, mod и тд, но почему-то нет инфы про создание данных композиций.  Кто-нибудь сталкивался с этим? Хотя бы покажите, где копать, а то, честно говоря, уже опускаются руки..

Answer (score 1):

Вот небольшой пример генерации кода взятый от [сюда](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1273219?start=0&tstart=0). Может поможет вам.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[ 1 ];;
AudioFormat af = new AudioFormat( (float )44100, 8, 1, true, false );
SourceDataLine sdl = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine( af );
sdl.open();
sdl.start();
for( int i = 0; i < 1000 * (float )44100 / 1000; i++ ) {
    double angle = i / ( (float )44100 / 440 ) * 2.0 * Math.PI;
    buf[ 0 ] = (byte )( Math.sin( angle ) * 100 );
    sdl.write( buf, 0, 1 );
}
sdl.drain();
sdl.stop();
```