# Проиграть звук из памяти при помощи JNI

Tags: java, аудио, jni

Я делаю игру на Java. И конечно, в игре должны быть звуки. Но как я понял, Sound API позволяет их проигрывать только из WAV файла. Мои 2 вопроса:
1. Загрузка из WAV файла это единственный способ воспроизвести звук в Sound API ?
2. Если да, то как управлять звуком в Java на наиболее низком уровне(в jni)?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, аудиоданные не обязательно читать из файла, можно их генерировать в программе. JNI не нужен. Очень подробное руководство есть на сайте Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/contents.html

Comment: Похожий вопрос с примером кода в ответе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/496096/java-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-keygen?rq=1